# Change of Coordinates for Surface Area Integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

When using the formula for the surface area integral and using some change of coordinates, *i.e.* spherical coordinates, does the area element *dA* change to $r^2sin(\phi)\partial\phi\partial\theta$ ?
Because I noticed in Dr. Paul Lamar's final example [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfaceIntegrals.aspx) he doesn't use the spherical area element. He simply uses the area element $\partial\phi\partial\theta$.

That's confusing to me. I feel like if he does a spherical change of coordinates, the area element he should be using is the spherical area element.

Comment: Exactly where? The final example (number 4) is a cylinder, so no spherical coordinates there...

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to Example 2 (the only example with spherical), then notice that he *does* conclude the surface element changes is $r^2\sin(\phi) d\phi d\theta$, where he calculates that $\|r_{\theta} \times r_{\phi}\| = 4 \sin{\phi}$. This is precisely what you want, since the radius of the sphere was $r = 2$. In that problem, he uses $dA$ to mean $d\phi d\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

My answer supplements Christopher's.  You are referring to Example 2 of [Dr. Paul Dawkins's notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfaceIntegrals.aspx).

Even though the partial sphere $S$ lives in Euclidean space $\mathbb R^3,$ notice that it had directly been parameterised in spherical coordinates from the get-go. Since there had not actually been a change of variables/coordinates from Cartesian to spherical, there was no occasion to explicitly change the area differential from, say, $\mathrm dx\mathrm dz,$ to $R^2\sinφ\:\mathrm dφ\mathrm dθ.$

In the formula (second cyan box) for the surface integral of a function on a surface $\mathbf r(u,v),$ note that the area differential $\mathrm dA$ lives in parameter space and simply stands for $\mathrm du\mathrm dv.$ So, it could be $$\mathrm dx\mathrm dz$$ or $$\mathrm dφ\mathrm dθ$$ or $$\mathrm dz\mathrm dxθ,$$ etc. It is not necessarily Cartesian, nor is it automatically substitutable with $r^2\sinφ\:\mathrm dφ\mathrm dθ$ whenever there are spherical coordinates.